# sql workbench adding rows after running a join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello everyone i have a quick question, i am running mysql workbench and after joining two tables i get as results 10000 rows. Considering that the first dataset got 6000 rows and the second 450, it'clearly wrong. i'm clearly doing something wrong but i can't figure what is that and why it is happening
I am selecting some column from the first data set and match it against the second one against sv3 and sv4 columns

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

the code

```
select media.Timestamp, media.Campaign, media.Media, media.sv3, media.sv4 
from media
inner join media_1
on media.sv3=media_1.sv3 and on media.sv4=media_1.sv4
```

Comment: There is zero chance a SELECT statement will add rows to the table. But why are you joining twice on the same conditions? `on media.sv3=media_1.sv3 and on media.sv3=media_1.sv3`

Comment: Get rid of second `on`.

Comment: i edited  the question the condition on media.sv3=media_1.sv3 and on media.sv3=media_1.sv3 was wrong

Answer (score 0):

JOIN queries yielding more results than their source records is not necessarily a sign something is outright wrong; but can be an indicator of something amiss (queries that need to behave that way exist, but are relatively rare).

The source of your issue is likely because you are joining on a value that is non-unique in both tables. As a simple example: If table X has **two** records with field A = 5, and table Y has **three** records with field A = 5, and they are JOINed on field A; those records will produce **six** results.

This may mean there is a problem with your source data, or you may just need to query it in a different manner. I notice you are only selecting fields from `media` and none from `media_1`; this query may yield the results you are expecting:

```
SELECT media.Timestamp, media.Campaign, media.Media, media.sv3, media.sv4 
FROM media
WHERE (sv3, sv4) IN (SELECT sv3, sv4 FROM media_1)
```

Comment: ok i tried how you suggested and i got 459 rows so it make more sense now, Can you tell me why the second query is producing a different result?

Comment: The query I supplied is not JOINing the records from the two tables, it is only selecting the records from the first table that have matching values in the second one; it doesn't care how many matches there were in the second one, just that there is one.

Comment: i have another question. let's say that after running your query i got matching for sv3 and sv3, how i can select just the sv3, sv4 with containing actual values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; but you do not need to SELECT the values you are checking against (using in WHERE/ON conditions).

Comment: i wasn't clear . i run your query and that's fine i got all the rows matching sv3 and sv4 within the second table. Now the issue is that some of the records for sv3 and sv4 are empy cause in both the tables of course in some instances are empty. my question is how i can run a query to get just the sv3,sv4 containg acutal values and avoid to have match for null records?

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is; it might be best if you edit the original question to contain: sample source data and sample results. Ideally, the results and data should demonstrate what should and should not be included, covering edge cases.